# Split a custom condition by regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm busy writing a backend module where users can create their own conditions/rules. Now I want to split a condition in parts.

For example:

> **Condition**: {variable} > 100

```
// desired output
Array
(
    [0] => {variable} > 100
)
```

> **Condition**: {variable} == {anotherVariable} OR {var} <= 10

```
// desired output
Array
(
    [0] => {variable} == {anotherVariable}
    [1] => OR
    [2] => {var} <= 10
)
```

> **Condition**: {variable} == {anotherVariable} AND {var} <= 10 AND {variable} == some string

```
// desired output
Array
(
    [0] => {variable} == {anotherVariable}
    [1] => AND
    [2] => {var} <= 10
    [3] => AND
    [4] => {variable} == some string
)
```

And after that I have to split the comparison into 3 parts:

> **Comparison:** {variable} == {anotherVariable}

```
// desired output
// allowed comparison operators are: ==, !=, >, >=, <, <=, <>
Array
(
    [0] => {variable}               // comparison
    [1] => ==                       // comparision operator
    [2] => {anotherVariable}        // comparison
)
```

I'm struggling for hours now with regular expressions but do not lead to the desired output.

Comment: Can they nest `AND` and `OR`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it wil be a great boost of functionality but I don't have a good answer for that in my array. It should do something with {var} > 10 AND ({var2} == something OR {var3} == something). Is it with regular expressions possible to have everything between () in a new array?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this. You will need to build your custom parser.

Comment: [`(.*?)\s*((?:(?:=|!|>|<)=)|>|<>?)\s*(.*?)\s*(AND|OR|$)\s*`](http://regex101.com/r/rV4iS7) (does not parse nested)

Comment: This does not seem to me like a problem that can be solved by regular expressions alone. In my opinion, you will need to add some programming logic too.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more simple I have assumed that strings are between double quotes.

The first part of the pattern defines (`(?(DEFINE)...)`) the needed elements with named subpatterns. There are simple elements first (*comparison operator, boolean operator, operand*), and more elaborated elements (*atomic condition, condition, check*). Each subpattern can be defined with the others and itself.

Once the define part is closed, the main pattern begins and captures three possible elements inside the "token" named capture at each iteration: *a boolean operator, an atomic condition (i.e. the most possible basic condition), or the whole condition inside parenthesis*

To succeed, the main pattern must pass one of two entry points, the first (that is used only one time) is the subpattern `\g<check>`. This subpattern ensures that the entire string is well formed from start to end, and since it is a zero-width assertion that begins with `\A`, forces the token search to start from the beginind of the string. The second entry point is `(?!\A)\G` and means "not at the begining of the string, contiguous to the precedent match". This entry is used for all other matches.

The `\g<par>` named capture is only here to be used by the recursive function. If the capture exists, the token is a whole condition inside parenthesis and need to be reparsed to produce an array.

```
define('PATTERN', <<<'EOD'
~
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<comp_op> [=!]= | >=? | <[=>]? )
  (?<bool_op> OR | AND )
  (?<operand> { \w+ } | -?\d+ | "[^"]+" ) # you can improve the " pattern

  (?<at_cond> \g<operand> \s+ \g<comp_op> \s+ \g<operand> ) # atomic cond
  (?<cond> \g<at_cond> (?> \s+ \g<bool_op> \s+ \g<cond> )* | \( \g<cond> \) )
  (?<check> (?= \A \s* \g<cond> \s* \z ) ) # checks the whole string format
)

(?: \g<check> \s* | (?!\A)\G \s+)
(?| (?<token>\g<bool_op>) | (\g<at_cond>) | \( (\g<cond>) )
(?<par> \) )? # only to test if a recursion is needed
~x
EOD
);

function getTokens ($str) {
    if (preg_match_all(PATTERN, $str, $matches)) {
        $tokens = array(); 
        foreach ($matches['token'] as $k=>$token) {
            $tokens[] = ($matches['par'][$k]) ? getTokens($token) : $token;
        }
        return $tokens;
    }
    return false;
}

$testset = array(
    '{variable} > 100',
    '{variable} == {zogabu} OR {buga} <= 10',
    '{meuh} == {zo} AND ({meuh} <= 10 OR {zomeuh} == "GABUZO")',
    '{BU} > 3 AND ({ga} == "ZO" OR ({bu} == "GA" AND {meuh} != "GA"))' );

foreach($testset as $test_string) {
    $result = getTokens($test_string);    
    echo "\ntest_string: $test_string\n" . print_r($result, true);
}
```